# Suggest me to find best programming/code practice in JAVA

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, optimization

I want to find out some coding tips to improve my code style and formats.

for example we are using ternary instead of if-else conditions just like.

With if-else condition.

```
String name = "Meet";
String desc;
if(name == null){
    desc = "Hello Guest";
} else {
    desc = "Hello " + name;
}
```

With ternary operator

```
String name = "Meet";
String desc = "Hello " + ((null == name) ? "Guest" : name);
```

Comment: I suggest using whatever you feel is most readable to the next person reading your code. Don't optimize where it's not going to make any difference.

Comment: Asking for "some coding tips" is way to vague and also when it comes to coding style very personal and therefore opinionated. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

One should follow good programming practices. i.e.

- Write code which is easy to understand, no doubt ternary operator removes some writing part, but if-else, can easily recognize, and faster to understand.
- Keep code simple, if you are have achieved certain time and space complexity, don't go for making it too complex.
- Use proper variable names like instead of writing `cid` for customer id, write `customerId`. Moreover, read about camel case notations, where the class name is written as like this `CustomerInfo`, while functions and variable as `getCustomerId()` or `customerId` respectively, and constant in uppercase `PIE`.
- Read more about [Programming Practices here](https://www.topcoder.com/coding-best-practices/)